# Rails: Nested Forms Not setting all fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-form-for

I'm trying to make Nested Form in rails and everything is ok ,

I'm saving The dynamic fields values in a Hstore field called Properties

and it's saving perfectly. like this

> properties: {"You have The Icon"=>"0", "we will create the icon"=>"1",
>   "is it normal colorz"=>"No", "Are you watching spacetoons"=>"No", "You
>   Have content"=>"foobar"}

The problem is when Editing I have the first  3 properties set in their fields perfectly whil the last two aren't

Here's the `fields_for` that i'm using

```
<%= f.fields_for :properties, OpenStruct.new(@project.properties) do  | builder | %>
    <% @project.project_type.fields.order(created_at: :asc).each do | field | %>
      <%= render "projects/fields/#{field.field_type}", field: field, f:builder %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

And the result is

[image]

any idea??

Comment: Can you post the related controller code and the params generated in the log?

Comment: the controller for this page is just 
def edit 
end 
 
and the log is simply
14:14:44 web.1  | Started GET "/projects/2/edit?_=1442146480405" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-13 14:14:44 +0200
14:14:44 web.1  | Processing by ProjectsController#edit as JS
14:14:44 web.1  |   Parameters: {"_"=>"1442146480405", "id"=>"2"}
14:14:44 web.1  |   Project Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]